# Has some problems with convering JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found interesting article here http://vk.com/away.php?utf=1&to=http%3A%2F%2Ftympanus.net%2FTutorials%2FAnimatedBorderMenus%2Findex3.html and tried to apply it on my site.

I found problem in conficting modernize + classie vs jquery
so I decided to convert code like that:
before:

```
function init() {
    var menu = document.getElementById( 'bt-menu' ),
        trigger = menu.querySelector( 'a.bt-menu-trigger' ),
        // triggerPlay only for demo 6
        triggerPlay = document.querySelector( 'a.bt-menu-trigger-out' ),
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
        resetMenu = function() {
            classie.remove( menu, 'bt-menu-open' );
            classie.add( menu, 'bt-menu-close' );
        },
        closeClickFn = function( ev ) {
            resetMenu();
            overlay.removeEventListener( eventtype, closeClickFn );
        };

    var overlay = document.createElement('div');
    overlay.className = 'bt-overlay';
    menu.appendChild( overlay );

    trigger.addEventListener( eventtype, function( ev ) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();

        if( classie.has( menu, 'bt-menu-open' ) ) {
            resetMenu();
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( menu, 'bt-menu-close' );
            classie.add( menu, 'bt-menu-open' );
            overlay.addEventListener( eventtype, closeClickFn );
        }
    });

    if( triggerPlay ) {
        triggerPlay.addEventListener( eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();

            classie.remove( menu, 'bt-menu-close' );
            classie.add( menu, 'bt-menu-open' );
            overlay.addEventListener( eventtype, closeClickFn );
        });
    }

}

init();
```

after:

```
function init() {
    var $menu = $( 'bt-menu' ),         
        eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
        resetMenu = function() {
            $menu.removeClass('bt-menu-open' );
            $menu.addClass('bt-menu-close' );
        },
        closeClickFn = function( ev ) {
            resetMenu();
            $overlay.unbind( eventtype, closeClickFn );
        };

    var $overlay = $("<div class='bt-overlay'/>");
        $menu.append( $overlay );

    $('bt-menu a.bt-menu-trigger').bind( eventtype, function( ev ) {
        alert('hi');
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();

        if( $menu.hasClass('bt-menu-open' ) ) {
            resetMenu();
        }
        else {
            $menu.removeClass('bt-menu-close' );
            $menu.addClass('bt-menu-open' );
            $overlay.bind( eventtype, closeClickFn );
        }
    });
}

init();
```

But it doesnt work and I don't know where is my error.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var $menu = $( 'bt-menu' )` should be `var $menu = $( '#bt-menu' )`.